# How to open first years uib-datepicker-popup? [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I open it calendar show with year and days. Can I make it somehow to first display years?

here is html:

```
<input style="width: 30%;float: left;" name="date" id="date" type="text" 
                           class="form-control" 
                           uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy"
                           ng-model="ctrl.userProfile.birthDate"
                           is-open="dpOpenStatus.withRequired"
                           ng-required />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" 
                                class="btn btn-default" 
                                ng-click="setDpOpenStatus('withRequired', $event)">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup), you can set the `datepicker-options` object's `datepickerMode` property to one of the following:

> datepickerMode C  (Default: day) - Current mode of the datepicker
>   (day|month|year). Can be used to initialize the datepicker in a
>   specific mode.

So, in your view, add this:

```
datepicker-options="options"
```

and in your controller, add this:

```
 $scope.options = {
   datepickerMode: 'year',
   minDate: new Date()
};
```

Comment: I have this implementation currently. What I am wondering is if you can append the century in front of the year? For example, it just shows 81-00 but does not tell the user if that is 1981, 1881, etc. Any ideas on this? I suppose the correct question is how to make it display a 4 digit year instead of 2 digits only.

Comment: @Kleigh Try adding this to your options: formatYear: 'yyyy',